# Is there a way to add on to the points of a shape/or a way to grab the perimeter points?

Tags: java

I currently have a shape made using

```
path.createTransformedShape(identity);
```

This is to go along with my game. I'm trying to use this rotated shape as my bounds for a rotating asteroid.

```
ast[n].setBounds(path.createTransformedShape(identity));
```

However, I have ran into the problem that the new shape's origin is at (0,0). So when I'm using my own intersects method its thinking this shape is at (0,0) when it should be at the current objects x and y coordinates.

The only way I can think to fix this is to add the x and y coordinates of the objects onto the shape. But I haven't found a way to get the perimeter points of the shape, or a way to shift the shape.

Comment: You can provide an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org)

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Like peeskillet said, you're more likely to get meaningful help if you edit your post to include some code showing exactly what your problem is.

Comment: Thank you David reading through that post I found the solution!